# Angular sass application doesn't recognize mixins at start

Tags: angular, sass, mixins, scss-mixins

I have an angular web application with sass implemented. It works fine but only when the last change is saved in "styles.scss" (being that file the one with the imports of the other scss files). When the project is launched saving from another file (or for the first time with ng serve) my mixins are not recognized and I get this error:

```
SassError: Undefined mixin.
  ╷
4 │         @include random-rgb();
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\app\app.component.scss 4:9  root stylesheet
```

This is my project structure:

[image]

And this is the stylesheet code:

**styles.scss**

```
@import '_variables.scss';
@import '_mixin.scss';
@import '_base.scss';
@import '../app/app.component.scss';
@import '../app/cabecera/cabecera.component.scss';

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/buttons";

/* Importing Bootstrap SCSS file. */
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```